# Nested "System.out.print" output

Tags: java, system.out

Why does this program:

```java
import java.io.*;

public class testpage
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        pri();
    }

    public static int p2 (int x)
    {
        System.out.print("p");
        return x * x + 1;
    }

    public static void pri ( )
    {
        int y = 3;
        System.out.print( p2(y) + "-" + p2(y));
    }
}
```

Output this:

```
pp10-10
```

Specifically, why would the output on each side of the `-` be different when the method calls are the same?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I edited your post to remove most of the unnecessary words. SO is a website about quality questions and answers that not only help you, but can also be used by the entire community for later consumption as well, as a reference. Please keep that "reference" goal in mind for future questions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Java will evaluate the operands of a binary operator such as `+` before performing the operation.  This means that `p2(y)` will be called twice before the concatenations happen.  The 2 method calls each print `p` before the concatenations, then `System.out.print` prints `10-10`.

The [JLS, Section 15.17.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7.2), covers this:

> The Java programming language guarantees that every operand of an operator (except the conditional operators &&, ||, and ? :) appears to be fully evaluated before any part of the operation itself is performed.

Answer (score 1):

Its evaluated like below

```
p2(y) +"-" + p2(y)
```

`p2(y)` is called first and that prints p and returned 10.

then  `"-"` will be evaluated  but it will be as it is.

then again 2nd `p2(y)` will be evaluated  which gives call again to method which prints p and returned 10.

Note : while evaluating operands return value is no where printed.

after evaluating operands

now whole expression becomes from `p2(y) +"-" + p2(y)` to

```
p2(y) -> p
- -> do nothing as its not call to any method
p2(y) ->p
```

so output comes as 
`p` first operand evaluation, `p` second operand evaluation and then `p2(y)` -> returned value substituted while cancatenating.

so output comes as

```
pp10-10
```

where `pp` is printed for operand evaluation and rest is during cancatenation.

any doubts  ?

Comment: I didn't realize that the "returns" would be printed at the very end. I understand now and appreciate the detailed explanation!